# MERGE using a table variable without an obvious matching criteria

Tags: sql, t-sql, merge, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an InfoPath form that users fill in. It gets assigned a unique report number, and on the report they can select zero or more affected parts each of which have a bunch of columns. This list of affected parts can change as the report is processed. Submitting or resubmitting the report to SharePoint calls a SQL stored procedure with parameters including the column data semicolon-delimited with one `NVARCHAR(MAX)` representing multiple rows in one column. The stored procedure parses the semicolon-delimited `NVARCHAR`s to fill in a table variable, then merges that table variable with the main table that will be used for data analysis. Everything works great when the user only has one affected part with a given part number per report (since my `MERGE` statement uses that to determine if it needs to update an existing row or create a new one), and initially that was an acceptable restriction. Rough SQL summary:

```
CREATE TABLE [Report_to_Parts](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Report_ID] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [PartNumberOrdered] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [OtherColumns] [nvarchar](255) NULL)

CREATE PROCEDURE [MergeReport_sp] 
    @paramReport_ID nvarchar(255),
    @paramPartNumberString nvarchar(MAX) = NULL,
    @paramOtherColumnsString nvarchar(MAX) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempPartTable TABLE (
        [Report_ID] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [PartNumberOrdered] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [OtherColumns] [nvarchar](255) NULL)

    DECLARE @WorkingPartNumberString nvarchar(255),
        @WorkingOtherColumnsString nvarchar(255)

    -- Magic to parse the semicolon delimited parameters omitted
    WHILE (PartsRemainingToParse)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tempPartTable (
            [Report_ID],
            [PartNumberOrdered],
            [OtherColumns])
        VALUES (
            @paramReport_ID,
            @WorkingPartNumberString,
            @WorkingOtherColumnsString)         
    END

    MERGE [Report_to_Parts]
    USING @tempPartTable AS [Source]
    ON (
        [Report_to_Parts].[Report_ID] = @paramReport_ID AND
        [Report_to_Parts].[PartNumberOrdered] = [Source].[PartNumberOrdered])
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN INSERT(
            [Report_ID],
            [PartNumberOrdered],
            [OtherColumns])
        VALUES (
            @paramReport_ID,
            [Source].[PartNumberOrdered],
            [Source].[OtherColumns])
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN UPDATE SET [OtherColumns]=[Source].[OtherColumns]
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND [Report_to_Parts].[Report_ID] = @paramReport_ID
        THEN DELETE;
END
```

Currently working inputs and results, assuming that parts with [Report_ID] of 123456 doesn't already exist in [Report_to_Parts] but a few other entries do:

```
EXEC MergeReport_sp
    @paramReport_ID = N'123456',
    @paramPartNumberString = N'Part 1;abcd-efg;Part 3;'
    @paramOtherColumnsString = N'There are many;other columns;but I simplified;'

SELECT * FROM [Report_to_Parts] WHERE [Report_ID] = N'123456'

---------------------------------------------------------
| ID | Report_ID | PartNumberOrdered | OtherColumns     |
| 05 | 123456    | Part 1            | There are many   |
| 06 | 123456    | abcd-efg          | other columns    |
| 07 | 123456    | Part 3            | but I simplified |

EXEC MergeReport_sp
    @paramReport_ID = N'123456',
    @paramPartNumberString = N'Part 1;Part 3;New Part;'
    @paramOtherColumnsString = N'Updates;Work;Too;'

SELECT * FROM [Report_to_Parts] WHERE [Report_ID] = N'123456'

-----------------------------------------------------
| ID | Report_ID | PartNumberOrdered | OtherColumns |
| 05 | 123456    | Part 1            | Updates      |
| 07 | 123456    | Part 3            | Work         |
| 08 | 123456    | New Part          | Too          |
```

But the following fails because it tries to base things off PartNumberOrdered:

```
EXEC MergeReport_sp
    @paramReport_ID = N'123456',
    @paramPartNumberString = N'Part 1;Part 1;'
    @paramOtherColumnsString = N'Thing 1;Thing 2;'
```

Now I need it to be able to gracefully handle reports with multiple parts sharing part numbers. Getting off InfoPath and/or SharePoint isn't an option, nor is removing the semicolon parsing aspect. Options I'm considering:

1. Every call of the stored procedure, delete all rows from [Report_to_Parts] that have a matching [Report_ID] and insert all @tempPartTable rows. This is the end result I want for data analysis, but I worry that it's terribly inefficient and that [ID] will get unnecessarily large as the system is used.
2. Change [Report_to_Parts] so it has a composite key of [ID] and [Report_ID] and figure out a way to have [ID] auto increment starting at 1 for each [Report_ID], then delete and insert as above.
3. Add a column to @tempPartTable for [ID], `SELECT` from [Report_to_Parts] to get [ID]s of parts already in the table for this [Report_ID], set @tempPartTable [ID]s based on that, and `MERGE` on [ID].
4. Change [Report_to_Parts] so it has a composite key, add a column to @tempPartTable for [ID] that auto increments starting at 1, and `MERGE` by [ID] and [Report_ID].

I'm having trouble coming up with the code for 3, and I'm definitely open to other ideas too. [Here's an earlier question I asked about this same system.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136848/what-to-do-when-sharepoint-lists-and-ssrs-isnt-enough)

Comment: Is it possible to create a view that could represent that delimited data as an actual table?  And could you then use the table as a more natural way to query the database?  I am honestly not sure if the view part is possible since it would seem to need a stored procedure to do the parsing.

Comment: @KingOfAllTrades Without the `WHILE` loop I'm pretty sure it wouldn't be possible to parse the strings. But I got the parsing working great. It's what to do with the results that I'm struggling with.

Comment: That is what I suspected too, but thought maybe you had a trick up your sleeve.  I am interested in this as I too use SharePoint as a database.  Ticket systems, application configuration and simple CRUD apps.  These work well and you can query the database pretty easy once you get the list guid.  Can you post sample data of what the table variable and the other table contain and the expected results?

Comment: @KingOfAllTrades Sample input and output posted. tempPartTable has exactly what [Report_to_Parts] ends up having if you filter by [Report_ID], but I could post that, too, if you'd like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing this question gave me some ideas and I was able to resolve this with option 4. I modified [Report_to_Parts] so that [ID] was not an identity, and was a Composite Primary Key along with [Report_ID]. Then I updated the stored procedure code (also including the parsing "magic" in case anyone stumbles upon this post trying to solve the parsing problem):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [MergeReport_sp]
    @paramReport_ID nvarchar(255),
    @paramPartNumberString nvarchar(MAX) = NULL,
    @paramOtherColumnsString nvarchar(MAX) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @tempPartTable TABLE (
        [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Report_ID] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [PartNumberOrdered] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [OtherColumns] [nvarchar](255) NULL)

    DECLARE @WorkingPartNumberString nvarchar(255),
        @WorkingOtherColumnsString nvarchar(255),
        @PartNumberPos int = CHARINDEX(N';', @paramPartNumberString),
        @OtherColumnsPos int = CHARINDEX(N';', @paramOtherColumnsString),
        @PartTableID int = 1

    WHILE (ISNULL(@PartNumberPos,0) > 0)
    BEGIN
        IF @OtherColumnsPos = 0 SET @OtherColumnsPos = 1

        SET @WorkingPartNumberString = NULLIF(SUBSTRING(@paramPartNumberString,1,@PartNumberPos - 1), '')
        SET @WorkingOtherColumnsString = NULLIF(SUBSTRING(@WorkingOtherColumnsString ,1,@OtherColumnsPos - 1), '')

        INSERT INTO @tempPartTable (
            [ID],
            [Report_ID],
            [PartNumberOrdered],
            [OtherColumns])
        VALUES (
            @PartTableID,
            @paramReport_ID,
            @WorkingPartNumberString,
            @WorkingOtherColumnsString)

        SET @PartTableID = @PartTableID + 1

        SET @paramPartNumberString = SUBSTRING(@paramPartNumberString, @PartNumberPos+1, LEN(@paramPartNumberString))
        SET @paramOtherColumnsString = SUBSTRING(@paramOtherColumnsString, @OtherColumnsPos +1, LEN(@paramOtherColumnsString))

        SET @PartNumberPos = CHARINDEX(N';',@paramPartNumberString)
        SET @OtherColumnsPos = CHARINDEX(N';',@paramOtherColumnsString)
    END

    MERGE [Report_to_Parts]
    USING @tempPartTable AS [Source]
    ON (
        [Report_to_Parts].[ID] = [Source].[ID] AND
        [Report_to_Parts].[Report_ID] = @paramReport_ID)
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
        THEN INSERT(
            [ID],
            [Report_ID],
            [PartNumberOrdered],
            [OtherColumns])
        VALUES (
            [Source].[ID],
            @paramReport_ID,
            [Source].[PartNumberOrdered],
            [Source].[OtherColumns])
    WHEN MATCHED
        THEN UPDATE SET
            [PartNumberOrdered] = [Source].[PartNumberOrdered]
            [OtherColumns]=[Source].[OtherColumns]
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND [Report_to_Parts].[Report_ID] = @paramReport_ID
        THEN DELETE;
END
```